# How to check a string exist in string set in dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have a string set in each item in my table. For example,

```
{                                        
   Title = "Book 101 Title"
   ISBN = "111-1111111111"
   Authors = "Author 1"
   Price = -2
   Dimensions = "8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5"
   PageCount = 500
   Color = [ "Red", "Black" ]
   ProductCategory = "Book" 
}


{                                        
   Title = "Book 102 Title"
   ISBN = "222-222222222"
   Authors = "Author 2"
   Price = -8
   Dimensions = "8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5"
   PageCount = 700
   Color = [ "Red", "Green" ]
   ProductCategory = "Book" 
}
```

With dynamoDB php sdk, I want to get items which is "Red" color. I try like this.

```
$response = $client->query(array(
    "TableName" => $tablename,
    "KeyConditions" => array(
        "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::CONTAINS,
        'Color' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array(Type::STRING_SET => array("Red"))
        ),
     )
));
```

But I got an error like that.

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator CONTAINS is not valid for SS AttributeValue type
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution from aws developer forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=351861#jive-message-351861). Can't use `CONTAINS` with `query`. Have to use it with `scan`. Like that.

```
$response = $client->scan(array(
    "TableName" => $tablename,
    "KeyConditions" => array(
        "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::CONTAINS,
        'Color' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array(Type::STRING => "Red")
        ),
     )
));
```

Answer (score 2):

The CONTAINS operator can only used on a range key. The only supported operator for hash key is EQ.

So, a tricky way to achieve searching in set is to set a dummy hash key (e.g. a column with constant value 1), and set an index with this dummy column as hash key and the set you want to search in as range key. Then, you can query by this index using hash key value 1 and range key  with operator CONTAINS.

P.S. Scan is a very bad operation. It is very low in efficiency, returning maximum of 1MB data at one time, in unpredictable order, and may cause throughput spike.

Comment: Thanks @MGhostSoft . Please show me some code example or link to refer.

Answer (score -2):

I've been reading [Amazon DynamoDB doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) and I think the problem is using `ComparisonOperator::CONTAINS`, I suggest you use `'CONTAINS'` instead.

So your code will be:

```
$response = $client->query(array(
    "TableName" => $tablename,
    "KeyConditions" => array(
        "ComparisonOperator" => 'CONTAINS',
        'Color' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array(Type::STRING_SET => array("Red"))
        ),
     )
));
```

Comment: Nope !! `ComparisonOperator::CONTAINS` is constant from `Aws\DynamoDb\Enum` . There is no problem with that.