# DynamoDB scan on field which is array of structures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table where one of the fields is an array of structures, each structure has several fields, let's say name and phone number. I want to make a (python, but it does not really matter) scan query for entries where one of the array entry's fields is the name that I need. Is that possible ? It is similar to the question

[dynamodb - scan items by value inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058134/dynamodb-scan-items-by-value-inside-array)

but in my case condition has to be on one of the fields of the structure:

```
FilterExpression: "contains(#user, :v)",
ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#users": "user" }, 
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":v": "John" }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its the same, one of the suggested solutions(by @Arkar Aung) queries by single attribute.

Comment: For some reason I do not see the answer you mention.

Comment: my bad, check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180853/how-to-check-a-string-exist-in-string-set-in-dynamodb/24181742#24181742